# How to enumerate a problem set in a book accordingly with the chapter number?

Tags: numbering, chapters, books

I am writing a book and in the end of each chapter I have a section with labeled problems that looks like this:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}

Bla bla bla...

\section*{Problems:}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{ch1_pr1} Prove...
\item \label{ch1_pr2} Calculate...
\item \label{ch1_pr3} Fill the details in...
\end{enumerate}
```

The issue with this approach is that every problems' section is numbered exactly the same way in every chapter (1, 2, 3, 4, etc...) so if, say, in chapter four I want to cite the first problem in the first chapter I will get in my book just '1' (the number one), which will make it confusing, since it is not making any reference to the chapter the problem I am citing belongs to.

So my question is: **How can I enumerate my problems so they take into account the chapter they belong to?**

I was thinking something like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... for the problems in chapter one, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, ... for the problems in chapter two, etc. But I don't know how to do that.

Since I am not very skilled with Latex, I would ask for the solution to my problem to be as simple as possible.

---

**Update:** Here is some sample code so you can compile it and better understand what I need:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

Bla bla bla...

\section*{Problems:}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{ch1_pr1} Prove...
\item \label{ch1_pr2} Calculate...
\item \label{ch1_pr3} Fill the details in...
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{Second}

Bla bla bla....

\section*{Problems:}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{ch2_pr1} Prove...
\item \label{ch2_pr2} Calculate...
\item \label{ch2_pr3} Fill the details in...
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{Third}

First problem in Chapter 1:~\ref{ch1_pr1}

First problem in Chapter 2:~\ref{ch2_pr1} \\

The issue: Different problems appear to be the same when cited!

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar solution using the `enumitem` package which makes it much easier to define new and customised lists. I also used `problems` for the environment name. Here, the label within the original problem set is just `1` or whatever, but the reference appears as `1.1` etc.

It is best not to use explicit numbers in your `\label{}`s in case you insert or remove items later. While LaTeX won't care two hoots, it tends to confuse human beings greatly if `chap3_prf5` refers to the problem numbered 9 in chapter 2.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problems]{label={\arabic*.}, ref={\thechapter.\arabic*}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

Bla bla bla \dots

\section*{Problems:}
\begin{problems}
  \item \label{pr:intro_prove} Prove \dots
  \item \label{pr:intro_calc} Calculate \dots
  \item \label{pr:intro_details} Fill the details in \dots
\end{problems}

\chapter{Pethau Pellach}
Fel dywedwyd ym mhroblem \ref{pr:intro_calc} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image: fel dywedwyd...]

If you would prefer the chapter number to appear in the original label as well, change

```
\setlist[problems]{label={\arabic*.}, ref={\thechapter.\arabic*}}
```

to

```
\setlist[problems]{label={\thechapter.\arabic*}}
```

[image: original labels, too]

Comment: @cfr I am having some trouble implementing your solution: the problems do appear enumerated as I suggested (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc...) but when I try to reference them elsewhere in the book, they appear as before (1, 2, 3, etc...).

Comment: @CarlRojas Did you compile twice?

Comment: @cfr Yes, several times indeed! But there is something strange: when I try the code you gave me in the toy example I posted before it worked, but when I try it in the actual book it didn't. Any idea why?

Comment: @Bernard Obviously explains why you were quicker ;).

Comment: @CarlRojas It really isn't possible to say without an example which reproduces the problem. Try eliminating stuff until you have a minimal non-working case and then ask a follow-up question. All I can really say is that something else in your code must be causing problems, but without knowing what code causes problems, what errors or warnings you get, whether the log says anything etc., it is difficult to say. Are you using any packages which modify the behaviour of `\ref{}`? A different class?

Comment: @cfr: B.t.w.: Didn't you add to the O.P.'s text some (possibly) fake Cymraeg?

Comment: @Bernard (1) Why do you think it is fake? (2) You don't think that's what makes my MWE work but not the real document? Add Welsh to solve mysterious LaTeX problems? [The MWE in the question was not enough to test in the original version.]

Comment: I have no idea whether its fake or not, as I'm not a native speaker, nor a speaker at all. I've just read about the Mabinogion. So I added this possibility just in case – might have been some private joke.

Comment: @Bernard It is not fake. Any errors in it are genuine mistakes. 'Problemau Pellach' -> ' Further Problems'; `Fel dywedwyd ym mhroblem...' -> 'As was seen in problem...'. (But probably there's a better way of beginning. On reflection, I may be mixing registers improperly. It is not my first language. And nobody speaks written/formal/literary Welsh as a first language.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, defining a new list, based on `enumerate`, with some specifications, that I named `problems` which has two levels:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[problems]{wide=0pt}
\setlist[problems, 1]{label =\thechapter.\arabic*, font=\bfseries, wide=0pt}
\setlist[problems,2]{label =(\alph*), wide =0.5em, topsep=2pt, itemsep =2pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

Bla bla bla...

\section*{Problems:}

\begin{problems}
  \item \label{ch1_pr1} Prove...
  \begin{problems}
    \item A first question
    \item Another silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question.
  \end{problems}
  \item \label{ch1_pr2} Calculate...
  \item \label{ch1_pr3} Fill the details in...Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{problems}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

Bla bla bla...

\section*{Problems:}

\begin{problems}
  \item \label{ch1_pr1} Prove...
  \begin{problems}
    \item A first question
    \item Another silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question. A silly question.
  \end{problems}
  \item \label{ch1_pr2} Calculate...
  \item \label{ch1_pr3} Fill the details in...Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]